# how can I copy these numbers in a range across row 2

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

What function in excel 2010 will let me look in the green area and copy the values in the brown area without any blank cells in between them. 
The first row in the green area is data from worksheet1 and the data in the second row of the green are is from worksheet2. 
I need to have the brown row show the green area values. Sometimes there might be 2 or 3 values in the first row of the green area and then nothing in the second row and then maybe nothing in the first row and a few in the second row. I hope I explained this well enough. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: In your example the brown area is only showing the first row of the green area's values. Is that what you want? Are you looking for an average? I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: I need the second row of the green area to join into the end of the brown area values....There is no math, just copy those numbers. Notice the range of the green area. There could be more numbers in either green area rows.

Comment: Copy the second row next to the first raw (0.111 under DUI BAC 6) ? Or concatenate 0.110 and 0.111 in a single array ? (resulting in a string for example)

Comment: Each number in its own cell across the brown area without any blank cells between them. So copy each value of the green area into the brown row, So 0.111 under DUI BAC 6 in this example. But if there are more numbers in the first row of the green area, I need it to accommodate those numbers then row 2 in the green area with no blank cells in between the brown cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the following formula which seems to achieve the goal you are looking for:

```
=IF(IF(A4 = "",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(5,1 + COUNTIF($A$4:A4,"") - 1)),A4)=0,"",IF(A4 = "",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(5,1 + COUNTIF($A$4:A4,"") - 1)),A4))
```

This is assuming that the first row in the green area starts at A4 (replace with your information). You should replace your brown row values with this formula.

This formula *looks* complicated but is in fact quite simple. The outermost IF statement checks if the result is zero - if so, it will return a blank cell. You can keep zeroes by simply using the inner:

```
=IF(A4 = "",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(5,COUNTIF($A$4:A4,""))),A4)
```

The formula then checks if the cell of the first green row below it is nothing - if so, it will read from the second green line (assuming it is on line *5*) by counting how many blank cells in the first green row there have already been and  converting this number to a column name. It then converts the column name and the row (*5*) to an address, and indirectly access that address. If the first green cell below it is not blank, it will simply copy that cell.

Edit: This formula had an error in it that was a result of me using A as my starting column. For your specific request you want to use:

```
=IF(IF(BH5 = "",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(6,60 + COUNTIF($BH$5:BH5,"") - 1)),BH5)=0,"",IF(BH5 = "",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(6,60 + COUNTIF($BH$5:BH5,"") - 1)),BH5))
```

At BH5-6. I added the "60" in the countif because column BH is column #60. If you move around your data you will have to update this number (although I'm sure there's a formula for it). The "-1" after the countif is necessary and easier than always typing in the column number -1 instead of replacing the column number.

Comment: Something is not right. It will not give me the second row at all. By the way my range starts at BH5 to BS6. I made the adjustments for the column/row. This is what I have for an adjusted formula.         =IF(IF(BH5 = "",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(6,COUNTIF($BH$5:BH5,""))),BH5)=0,"",IF(BH5 = "",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(6,COUNTIF($BH$5:BH5,""))),BH5))

Comment: You were correct. It was a mistake on my part that arose due to creating the formula on column A and not thinking ahead. My bad!